# Почему возникает ошибка в switch-case?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ошибка: "значение метки случая уже есть в данном переключателе в строке

```
switch (str[i])
    {
    case ')' || '}' || ']':

        if (st.empty())
        {
            count = i + 1;
            return false;
            
        }

        else if ((str[i] == ')' && st.top() == '(') || (str[i] == '}' && st.top() == '{') || (str[i] == ']' && st.top() == '['))
        {
            st.pop();
            
        }
        break;

    case '(' || '{' || '[':
        st.push(str[i]);
        count++;
        break;
```

[image]

[image]

На первой картинке ошибка ссылается на строку во второй картинке

Comment: Возможно в case дублируется значение типа bool

Comment: Про строку с `else if`: если встречая открывающую скобку, помещать в стек парную закрывающую, код проверки сократится до одного равенства. Код, кладущий в стек, усложнится, конечно, но в целом код станет проще.

Answer (score 5):

Запись `')' || '}' || ']'` возвращает всегда булевое значение, то-есть правду или в числах 1. И `switch` сравнивает букву `str[i]` всегда только с одним числом, то-есть с результатом выражения, в вашем случае с единицей или буквой с кодом один : `'\01'`.
Чтобы выполнялся один код на разных аргументах запись должна быть другой :

```
case ')' :
case '}' :
case ']' :
  код
  break ;
```

Answer (score 1):

в `case` дублируется значение типа bool. `case: ('(' || '{' || '[')` и `case: (')' || '}' || ']')`

error: duplicate case value